# execution order of startup task and auto-delayed windows service

Tags: powershell, windows-services

I am wondering, if I have a windows service (auto-delayed) and a scheduled startup powershell script task, can windows make sure the execution order? which one will run firstly?

Answer (score 0):

You could for example wait in your scheduled startup script until a specific service is running:

```
while (Get-Service -Name 'Your_Service' | where Status -ne 'Running')
{
    Sleep -Seconds 1    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want the windows service runs after the startup script? or do you mean startup script will always run before the windows service started?

Comment: I don't know the execution order but I doubt that a auto-delayed windows service will wait until all startup tasks are finished. You could change the startup type to manuell and start the windows service yourself within your startup task?